# Cant' dual install Xubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7, xubuntu

Had Xubuntu 12.04 installed on my computer. Later on I decided to dual install Windows 7. I opened up GParterd and created a partition for Windows 7 and formatted it at NTSF. Well, when I try to install Windows 7, it doesn't recognized the NTSF partition. It states that all the partitions are GPT file format. Even though I have gone in and reformatted that partition several times as NTSF, Windows 7 still won't recognize it at anything other than GPT file system. I even used a Gparted lived CD to format that partition as well. How do I format the partition in NTSF where Windows 7 will recognize it as such and install onto it?

Comment: My Linux friends tell me that generally installing Windows messes up GRUB. If no answer is provided, I suggest taking a backup, wiping Xubuntu with a clean Windows 7 install, and then reinstalling Xubuntu alongside Windows 7. Linux is used to being with other OSes, Windows isn't used to being with other OSes generally.

Comment: You can see GPT as a property of the disk. It's not a property of the partition, nor one of the filesystem. You can have a MBR-formatted disk with an NTFS-formatted partition, and a GPT-formatted disk with an NTFS-formatted partition, independently. You can choose the partitioning scheme in the "Device" >> "Create partition table" menu of Gparted, where MBR is listed as msdos. Please note that changing the partitioning scheme, you will lose all the partitions, and have to recreate them from scratch. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

gpt is not a format, but a type of partitioning. Windows only boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. Ubuntu will boot either with UEFI or BIOS from gpt partitioned drives.

You may be able to convert, if partitioning is within certain MBR rules, so you then can boot with BIOS. Or if system is dual UEFI/BIOS you have to convert your Windows install to a flash drive and add the UEFI capability.

Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html
You then need to use gdisk to convert from gpt to MBR
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr